# Get ELB ARN as an output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

I need to get a Classic ELB's ARN as an output in order to export it. Any idea on how to achieve this?

I tried following code with below error.

```
Outputs:
  LoadBalancer:
    Description: A reference to the Application Load Balancer/ARN
    Value: 
      'Fn::GetAtt': [ LoadBalancer, Arn ]
```

> Error Template validation error: Template error: resource LoadBalancer
>   does not support attribute type Arn in Fn::GetAtt

For **ALB**s following code works. But for Classic ELBs it just returns the name.

```
Outputs:
  LoadBalancer:
    Description: A reference to the Application Load Balancer/ARN
    Value: !Ref LoadBalancer
    Export: 
      Name: SO-LoadBalancer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classic ELB does not have an ARN as a [return value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html#aws-properties-ec2-elb-ref), you can construct your own [Classic ELB's ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-elb) and export it.

```
Outputs:
  LoadBalancer:
    Description: A reference to the Classic Load Balancer/ARN
    Value: !Sub 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:loadbalancer/${LoadBalancer}'
    Export: 
      Name: SO-LoadBalancer
```

Comment: Can you share the full output code? Not sure how to use yours in there

Comment: Thanks, it works! Any idea where I can verify it? I don't see an ARN in the classic ELB descriptions.